# Is it possible to see iOS screenshots on the Mac directly (with some kind of auto-share)?

Tags: macos, ios, mac, icloud, screen-capture

iOS (as well, now, as iPadOS) has a `Files` app. After taking a screenshot, the file can be found through the `Files` app.

But suppose that the point of taking the screenshot is to use it from macOS. Is there a way to see the screenshot directly on the Mac without first going through the `share` dance (I usually go to `Notes`—once syncing to `iCloud` completes, the file(s) will be available on `Notes` on the Mac, but I'm sure many other options are possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasteboard is synchronized between iOS and macOS using the same iCloud account. After you take a screenshot you can just copy the image and paste it on your mac.